# How to set the attribute name of a Spring session scoped bean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Given a spring bean that is configured with session scope such as:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS,value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
public class SomeBean {
}
```

Is there some way to control the name that Spring will store the bean under in the http session?

By default spring seams to use the session key `scopedTarget.someBean` is there anything I can add to the annotations to explicitly specify the attribute name in the Session?

Comment: Not without re-implementing the `SessionScope` as provided by Spring. The session scoped beans are meant to be used by Spring, they aren't meant to store things in the session and you obtaining them in a page (or whatever) to display information.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use:

```
@Component (value="mySpecialName")
@Scope (value="session")
```

Comment: that does not work, the component ends up with the id of "mySpecialName" but in the session the attribute that the bean is stored under is still scopedTarget.mySpecialName I really want to control the attribute in the http session that the session scoped installed is stored under

Comment: I've change my answer to include @Scope. In my code, I didn't need to set the proxyMode.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The `scopedTarget` part is hardcoded in the scoped proxy creation in Spring. So without rewriting parts of the framework that simply isn't possible.

The name is hardcoded in the [`ScopedProxyBeanDefinitionDecorator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/config/ScopedProxyBeanDefinitionDecorator.java#L56) which delegates to the [`ScopedProxyUtils`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/scope/ScopedProxyUtils.java#L106).

The fact that you use a scoped proxy is something internal for the framework. You probably want to use it to store something in the session and retrieve it in a page or something like that. Don't, just expose the regular bean which will delegate to the proper scoped instance.